# ng-change and ng-click not working in toggle button bootstrap-toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

ng click or ng-change not working in toggle button. I use toggle-bootstrap package here

```
<input checked 
       data-toggle="toggle" 
       data-size="small" 
       type="checkbox"
       data-on="16x9" 
       data-off="4x3"
       ng-true-value="'16x9'"
       ng-false-value="'4x3'"
       ng-model="slideMode" 
       ng-change="setSlideMode()">
```

Angular code

```
 $scope.slideMode = '16x9';
 $scope.setSlideMode = function(){
        console.log($scope.slideMode);
 };
```

Comment: can you share working code?

Comment: see there can be so many possibilities for which your might not working so you need to share some working environment with us

Comment: code typo for the value set to $scope.slideMode !

Comment: check now @GopinathShiva

Comment: creating a fiddle would be more useful indeed

Comment: Did you checked my answer? @GurpreetSingh

Answer (score 3):

you should add ngModel directive to input component:

```
 <input
    ng-model="check"
   data-toggle="toggle" 
   type="checkbox" 
   ng-change="test()">
```

than add check variable to your controller

```
 $scope.check = true;
```

here is the plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/r21V3E4upBNxIm16zakj?p=preview

Comment: plunkr not working. neither it shows checkbox nor atleast the name rendered

Comment: add this but stil not working i use bootstap toggle here

Comment: hey I update plunker, it was my mistake shared wrong url, sorry @ismailbaig

Comment: thanks. removing the down-vote and adding the up-vote :)

Comment: @oguzhan00 In normal checkbox its working fine but when use #bootstrap-toggle pachage its not working [http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/]

Comment: I think you should use ui-bootstrap or twitter bootstrap toggle. Or check this project's issues and make sure that this component can use with angularjs directive synchronously.  @GurpreetSingh

Comment: @oguzhan00 i think u ryt (y)

Answer (score 2):

Set **scope value syntax** is wrong.

```
$scope.slideMode = '16x9';
```